# Debug Angular2 App

Tags: debugging, angular

sorry for this lame question. I think it will be obvious for you, but not for me. I want to debug my application written in VS2015 Community, Angular2. I don't know how can I place breakpoints, see the variable contents and so on. This is pretty basic stuff, but I can't figure it out. Can somebody explain this to me?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it works to debug in VS2015.

It works pretty well in Chrome dev tools --> Source Page --> ctrl + P --> and search for a file, you can have there also **.ts** source files and you can add breakpoints.

Comment: Thanks, tibbus, I've tried it and it works. Sorry again for this kind of question, but I'm much more Win App developer and I'm quite new to JS/Ang2. I haven't tried the breakpoints / watches and other common things yet, but I suppose it will work. At least I was able to see the error messages which quided me to correction of my app. Will test the other debug features later :)